# How do exceptions work in Haskell (part two)?

Tags: exception, haskell

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception (throwIO, Exception)
import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Word (Word16)
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

data ArgumentParserException = WrongArgumentCount | InvalidPortNumber
    deriving (Show, Typeable)

instance Exception ArgumentParserException

data Arguments = Arguments Word16 FilePath String

main = do
    args <- return []
    when (length args /= 3) (throwIO WrongArgumentCount)

    let [portStr, cert, pw] = args
    let portInt = readMaybe portStr :: Maybe Integer
    when (portInt == Nothing) (throwIO InvalidPortNumber)

    let portNum = fromJust portInt
    when (portNum < 0 || portNum > 65535) (throwIO InvalidPortNumber)

    return $ Arguments (fromInteger portNum) cert pw

-- Newer 'base' has Text.Read.readMaybe but alas, that doesn't come with
-- the latest Haskell platform, so let's not rely on it
readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
readMaybe s = case reads s of
    [(x, "")] -> Just x
    _         -> Nothing
```

Its behavior differs when compiled with optimizations on and off:

```
crabgrass:~/tmp/signserv/src% ghc -fforce-recomp Main.hs && ./Main
Main: WrongArgumentCount
crabgrass:~/tmp/signserv/src% ghc -O -fforce-recomp Main.hs && ./Main
Main: Main.hs:20:9-34: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern [portStr, cert, pw]
```

Why is this? I am aware that [imprecise exceptions can be chosen from arbitrarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070690/how-do-exceptions-in-haskell-work); but here we are choosing from one precise and one imprecise exception, so that caveat should not apply.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Which GHC version are you using? I see the same behavior with GHC 7.6.2.

Comment: @hammar It happens on at least 7.6.1 and 7.4.1 here, and the person who brought it up in #haskell was using a 7.0.x.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's strange, because on 7.0.2 and 7.0.4, I get `WrongArgumentCount`. (Also 6.12.3)

Comment: @DanielFischer Hm, my memory is probably faulty, then. In any case, I know it was neither 7.4.1 nor 7.6.1 because I had to change the cabal file he sent me to relax the dependency on base. =)

Comment: Changed with 7.2 for me, so it was probably a 7.2.x.

Comment: I've been able to reduce it [to this shorter example](http://hpaste.org/88323).

Comment: @hammar Great, thanks. I tried half a dozen different things to make it smaller, but everything *I* could think of made it behave the way I expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would agree with hammar, this looks like a bug. And it seems fixed in HEAD since some time. With an older `ghc-7.7.20130312` as well as with today's HEAD `ghc-7.7.20130521`, the `WrongArgumentCount` exception is raised and all the other code of `main` is removed (bully for the optimiser). Still broken in 7.6.3, however.

The behaviour changed with the 7.2 series, I get the expected `WrongArgumentCount` from 7.0.4, and the (optimised) core makes that clear:

```
Main.main1 =
  \ (s_a11H :: GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld) ->
    case GHC.List.$wlen
           @ GHC.Base.String (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Base.String) 0
    of _ {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim.raiseIO#
               @ GHC.Exception.SomeException @ () Main.main7 s_a11H
        of _ { (# new_s_a11K, _ #) ->
        Main.main2 new_s_a11K
        };
      3 -> Main.main2 s_a11H
    }
```

when the length of the empty list is different from 3, raise `WrongArgumentCount`, otherwise try to do the rest.

With 7.2 and later, the evaluation of the length is moved behind the parsing of `portStr`:

```
Main.main1 =
  \ (eta_Xw :: GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld) ->
    case Main.main7 of _ {
      [] -> case Data.Maybe.fromJust1 of wild1_00 { };
      : ds_dTy ds1_dTz ->
        case ds_dTy of _ { (x_aOz, ds2_dTA) ->
        case ds2_dTA of _ {
          [] ->
            case ds1_dTz of _ {
              [] ->
                case GHC.List.$wlen
                       @ [GHC.Types.Char] (GHC.Types.[] @ [GHC.Types.Char]) 0
                of _ {
                  __DEFAULT ->
                    case GHC.Prim.raiseIO#
                           @ GHC.Exception.SomeException @ () Main.main6 eta_Xw
                    of wild4_00 {
                    };
                  3 ->
```

where

```
Main.main7 =
  Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.run
    @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer Main.main8 Main.main3

Main.main8 =
  GHC.Read.$fReadInteger5
    GHC.Read.$fReadInteger_$sconvertInt
    Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec.minPrec
    @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
    (Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.$fMonadP_$creturn
       @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)

Main.main3 = case lvl_r1YS of wild_00 { }

lvl_r1YS =
  Control.Exception.Base.irrefutPatError
    @ ([GHC.Types.Char], [GHC.Types.Char], [GHC.Types.Char])
    "Except.hs:21:9-34|[portStr, cert, pw]"
```

Since [`throwIO`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#v:throwIO) is supposed to respect ordering of `IO` actions,

> The `throwIO` variant should be used in preference to throw to raise an exception within the `IO` monad because it guarantees ordering with respect to other `IO` operations, whereas throw does not.

that should not happen.

You can force the correct ordering by using a `NOINLINE` variant of `when`, or by performing an effectful `IO` action before throwing, so it seems that when the inliner sees that the `when` does nothing except possibly throwing, it decides that order doesn't matter.

(Sorry, not a real answer, but try to fit that in a comment ;)

Comment: Thanks. Filed a bug [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7924); we'll see if the GHC devs agree.

Comment: You'll probably learn that it is already fixed, I just tried HEAD, and that works as expected.