# Evaluation (or none at all) of `_` Function Argument?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Given the data type, `Foo`:

```
Prelude> data Foo a = Foo a
```

It does not implement `Show`, so it can't be printed.

```
Prelude> Foo 5
<interactive>:13:1:
    No instance for (Show (Foo a0)) arising from a use of ‘print’
```

However, given a function that always throws:

```
Prelude> let f _ = error("bad!")
```

`f` can be applied to it.

```
Prelude> f (Foo 5)
*** Exception: bad!
```

Since `f` always throws for its single argument, does that mean that its argument is never evaluated, not even to Weak Head Normal Form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function "f" never evaluates its argument, as you say. This has nothing to do with whether the argument is an instance of "Show".

You could also say

```
Prelude> let f2 _ = "Some value"

Prelude> f2 (Foo 5)
"Some value"
```

But the real point is that even if the argument to f2 is undefined it will not be evaluated, and so will not throw an exception

```
Prelude> f2 undefined
"Some value"
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the argument of `f` is not evaluated. An easy way to test this is to use [`undefined`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:undefined), which will throw an error as soon as it's touched:

```
>>> undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

>>> let f _ = "bad"

>>> f undefined
"bad"
```

but you can write a similar function that does evaluate its argument to WHNF using [`seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq):

```
>>> let g a = a `seq` "bad"
>>> g undefined
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

or [`BangPatterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html):

```
>>> :set -XBangPatterns 
>>> let h !_ = "bad"
>>> h undefined 
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

or pattern match:

```
>>> let k (Foo _) = "bad"
>>> k undefined 
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

but you can do a [lazy pattern match](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match) using `~`:

```
>>> let j ~(Foo _) = "bad"
>>> j undefined 
"bad"
```

Comment: Due to the [nature of imprecise exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11070690/791604), seeing that `f undefined` throws a different error than `undefined` is _not_ good evidence that `f` is lazy. Even with `f x = x \`seq\` error "bad"`, a compiler is allowed to throw the "bad" exception instead of the one you get from `x` -- in a pinch, any old exception you have lying around will do.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it to just return the string "bad".

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude> let f _ = error("bad!")
```

Haskell is [lazy](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/fall14/spring13/lectures/06-laziness.html), the `_`param is not evaluated at all.

> The slogan to remember is “pattern matching drives evaluation”. To
>   reiterate the important points:
>
> ```
> Expressions are only evaluated when pattern-matched
>
> …only as far as necessary for the match to proceed, and no farther!
> ```