# What's the difference between throw and throwIO

Tags: haskell, exception

[The documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throwIO) says:

> The throwIO variant should be used in preference to throw to raise an exception within the IO monad because it guarantees ordering with respect to other IO operations, whereas throw does not.

I'm still confused after reading it. Is there an example to show that throw will cause a problem whereas throwIO will not?

Additional question:

Is the following statement correct?

1. If `throw` is being used to throw an exception in an IO, then the order of the exception is not guaranteed.
2. If `throw` is being used to throw an exception in a non-IO value, then the order of the exception is guaranteed.

If I need to throw an exception in a Monad Transformer, which I have to use `throw` instead of `throwIO`, does it guarantee the order of the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the docs could be improved. The issue you need to keep in mind with `throw` and the like is that `throw` returns a bottom value that "explodes" (raises an exception) when evaluated; but whether and when evaluation happens is difficult to control due to laziness.

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> let f n = if odd n then throw Underflow else True
Prelude Control.Exception> snd (f 1, putStrLn "this is fine")
this is fine
```

This could arguably be what you want to happen, but usually not. e.g. rather than the tuple above you might end up with a big data structure with a single exploding element that causes an exception to be raised after your web server returns 200 to the user, or something.

`throwIO` allows you to sequence raising an exception just as if it was another IO action, so it can be tightly controlled:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> throwIO Underflow >> putStrLn "this is fine"
*** Exception: arithmetic underflow
```

...just like doing `print 1 >> print 2`.

But note that you can actually *replace `throwIO` with `throw`*, for instance:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> throw Underflow >> putStrLn "this is fine"
*** Exception: arithmetic underflow
```

Since now the exploding value is of type `IO a`. It's actually not clear to me why `throwIO` exists other than to document an idiom. Maybe someone else can answer that.

As a final example, this has the same issue as my first example:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> return (throw Underflow) >> putStrLn "this is fine"
this is fine
```

Comment: There's a bit more to it than this, too.  `throw` results in imprecise exceptions - GHC is allowed to rewrite code in weird ways when they're involved, because GHC is allowed to consider all bottoms to be equivalent. `throwIO` prevents rewriting in that way - the exception you get will be the one thrown in the way you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, here's a relevant answer on that point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070690/how-do-exceptions-in-haskell-work

Comment: What is a Haskell program? A Haskell program is a pure set of equations that produces an imperative program called `main`, and the data type for “imperative program” is `IO ()`. throw, error, and undefined all cause a *pure* expression to fail. They don’t just mean an error has ocurred in the program; they mean *there is no program*. throwIO is a well-formed program that fails. It actually confuses *me* that many functions in the standard library, e.g. `catch`, don’t make a distinction between them.

Answer (score 2):

`throw` is a generalization of `undefined`, while `throwIO` is an actual `IO` action. A key difference is that many laws don't quite hold when strictness is considered (i.e., when you have `undefined` (or `throw`) and `seq`).

```
> (throw Underflow :: IO ()) `seq` ()
*** Exception: arithmetic underflow
> (throw Underflow >>= pure) `seq` ()
()
```

Hence contradicting the law `m >>= pure = m`. `throwIO` doesn't have that issue, so it is the more principled way of throwing exceptions.