# Why "error" function prints Exception many times

Tags: haskell

I was wondering why error function returns this in ghci:

First with one call:

```
Prelude> error ""
*** Exception: 
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:3:1 in interactive:Ghci1
```

Then with two:

```
Prelude> error (error "")
*** Exception: *** Exception: 
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:2:8 in interactive:Ghci1
```

And with three and so on:

```
Prelude> error (error ( error ""))
*** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: 
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:1:16 in interactive:Ghci1
```

Why there are many "*** Exception:" printed as error stacked?

I made this function that recieves a number and print exception that amount of times too:

```
printException n = foldr (\c r -> c error r) id (replicate n (.)) ""
```

But I was wondering also why

```
until (const False) error ""
```

Does not print Exception indefinitely.

Comment: You might also like to read answers to [one of my questions from a few years back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11070690/791604).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error` is lazy and the `String` is evaluated lazily as well. Also, since `error :: String -> a`, the result of `error` can be the input of the function `error`. And strings also are printed lazily, char by char.

Maybe to understand more the situation, you can think, for example, in a function like this:

`errorsFrom n = error (show n ++ "\n" ++ errorsFrom (n+1))`

Then evaluate on the console `errorsFrom 0`, and you will see this:

```
*** Exception: 0
*** Exception: 1
*** Exception: 2
*** Exception: 3
*** Exception: 4
*** Exception: 5
*** Exception: 6
*** Exception: 7
*** Exception: 8
*** Exception: 9
*** Exception: 10
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an error **in the message of the error**. Due to laziness when it prints the outer error, it raises the inner one which will print a second one.

It thus will start printing the message:

```
*** Exception: …
```

but then it starts the `putStrLn` of the message. Note that this message was *not* yet evaluated. Indeed, Haskell is lazy, it will thus only evaluate the message if it is going to print it, so now a second error is raised, and so it starts printing the second message.

> But I was wondering also why
>
> ```
> until (const False) error ""
> ```
>
> Does not print the exception indefinitely.

Here it starts printing the string, but it never will generate anything. Indeed, it will produce an expression that looks like `error (error (error (…  (error "") …)))`, but it will never evaluate any `error`, not even the outer one, since it keeps busy constructing a gigantic expression tree.

Answer (score 2):

Let `e` be any expression of type `String`. Then, `error e` raises an exception, which (in normal conditions) prints `*** Exception:` followed by the string `e`.

Hence, `e` is now being evaluated (not any earlier!). That might involve evaluating another `error e'`, which would print another `*** Exception:` followed by `e'`.

And so on.

The key point here is that `e` is evaluated lazily, only when it is being printed, so we observe `*** Exception:` in front of it.

For the last question, note that `until (const False) f x` will never evaluate any `f (f (f ... (f x))`. This is because, by laziness, `const False x`, `const False (f x)`, `const False (f (f x))`, ... do not need to evaluate `x`, nor `f x`, nor `f (f x)`, ...

Hence, in your example `error` is never really called.